# Azure Data factory - Web Activity failed with error code 2108

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

In ADF I have a pipeline to trigger Power BI Dataflow refresh. In that pipeline we have a web activity to trigger the Dataflow refresh but it keeps getting failed with different error messages with error code 2108 like:-

1. User Configuration Issue
2. HttpStatusErrorCode - 503 Service Unavailable

Note: The web activity works fine usually but once in a while I am getting these kind of error.

Can anyone provide any fix or hints for this to avoid getting these type of errors in future.

Comment: Error code 503 indicates that the web activity that you invoked has crashed or errored out, nothing you could do - or you sent some incorrect input payload. Seems your web service to be fixed rather than your pipeline activity.

Comment: The web activity is to automatically trigger the Dataflow refresh in PowerBI. As the web activity failed I had to manually trigger the PowerBI dataflow refresh

Answer (score 1):

A 503 Service Unavailable Error is an HTTP response status code that indicates your web server operates properly, but it can't handle a request at the moment. Since it's just a generic error message, it's difficult to pinpoint the issue's exact cause.
Still you can try below checks:

1. Reboot your server.
2. Check to see if your web server is going through maintenance.
3. Fix faulty firewall configurations.
4. Sift through your server-side logs.
5. Comb through your website's code to find bugs.

The web activity will timeout with similar error if it does not receive a response from the endpoint.